# How to find smallest value in JSON and subtract other elements with that value?

Tags: php, json

I need to find the smallest value in JSON object of particular key and subtract all keys with that value.

```
$print = '{"Table":[
{"Column":2,"Length":1,"Number":"A4","Row":12}, 
{"Column":2,"Length":1,"Number":"A3","Row":11},
{"Column":2,"Length":1,"Number":"A2","Row":9},
{"Column":2,"Length":1,"Number":"A1","Row":8},  
{"Column":3,"Length":1,"Number":"B4","Row":12},
{"Column":3,"Length":1,"Number":"B3","Row":11},
{"Column":3,"Length":1,"Number":"B2","Row":9},
{"Column":3,"Length":1,"Number":"B1","Row":8},
{"Column":4,"Length":1,"Number":"C4","Row":12},
{"Column":4,"Length":1,"Number":"C3","Row":11},  
{"Column":4,"Length":1,"Number":"C2","Row":9},
{"Column":4,"Length":1,"Number":"C1","Row":8}],"ResponseStatus":200,"Message":null}';
```

In the above JSON data, I want to get least value of "Row", e.g least value of above JSON data ROW is "8" and I want to subtract remaining ROWs with this least value. So that I will get JSON data as given below.

```
$print = '{"Table":[
    {"Column":2,"Length":1,"Number":"A4","Row":4}, 
    {"Column":2,"Length":1,"Number":"A3","Row":3},
    {"Column":2,"Length":1,"Number":"A2","Row":1},
    {"Column":2,"Length":1,"Number":"A1","Row":0},  
    {"Column":3,"Length":1,"Number":"B4","Row":4},
    {"Column":3,"Length":1,"Number":"B3","Row":3},
    {"Column":3,"Length":1,"Number":"B2","Row":1},
    {"Column":3,"Length":1,"Number":"B1","Row":0},
    {"Column":4,"Length":1,"Number":"C4","Row":4},
    {"Column":4,"Length":1,"Number":"C3","Row":3},  
    {"Column":4,"Length":1,"Number":"C2","Row":1},
    {"Column":4,"Length":1,"Number":"C1","Row":0}],"ResponseStatus":200,"Message":null}';
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: @NaveenPrasath I edit my answer, at first time I think that you want the last element, the code work with the min, take a look to my answer ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the least by getting all rows then just use `min()` function. Then after getting that, loop again and make subtractions with using reference `&`, then re encode. Rough example:

```
$rows = array();
$print = json_decode($print, true); // decode
foreach($print['Table'] as $val) { $rows[] = $val['Row']; }
$least = min($rows); // get least // $least = min(array_column($print['Table'], 'Row'));
foreach($print['Table'] as &$val) {
    $val['Row'] -= $least; // make subtractions
}
$print = json_encode($print); // re encode
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/O6hCt2)

Comment: Thank you for your valuable information. This works great with all types of JSON date. I once again thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here your code if you use PHP >= 5.5.0:

```
    <?php

$print = '{"Table":[
{"Column":2,"Length":1,"Number":"A4","Row":12}, 
{"Column":2,"Length":1,"Number":"A3","Row":11},
{"Column":2,"Length":1,"Number":"A2","Row":9},
{"Column":2,"Length":1,"Number":"A1","Row":8},  
{"Column":3,"Length":1,"Number":"B4","Row":12},
{"Column":3,"Length":1,"Number":"B3","Row":11},
{"Column":3,"Length":1,"Number":"B2","Row":9},
{"Column":3,"Length":1,"Number":"B1","Row":8},
{"Column":4,"Length":1,"Number":"C4","Row":12},
{"Column":4,"Length":1,"Number":"C3","Row":11},  
{"Column":4,"Length":1,"Number":"C2","Row":9},
{"Column":4,"Length":1,"Number":"C1","Row":8}],"ResponseStatus":200,"Message":null}';


$obj = json_decode($print, true);

$min = min(array_column($obj['Table'], 'Row'));

foreach($obj['Table'] as $key => $value) {
    $obj['Table'][$key]['Row'] -= $min; 
}   

$out = json_encode($obj);

echo $out;

?>
```